Sourcetree commit page view missing files

Hi guys, I wondering anyone have same issue with me. I have 2 modified file, but I dono why my Sourcetree commit page only show 1 file info, I can't find any where to select another file.
Before this it should display something like this.

This been annoyed me for weeks.
